# Nginx redirect www to non www

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-location

Quick question, I'm not a nginx expert in any means therefore little stuck. Tried several things but I guess im doing something wrong.

I've got this setup:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
          allow all;
          root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_buffer_size 8k;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @nodejs;
        }

        location @nodejs {
                proxy_pass http://nodejs:8080;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
                add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
                # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
                # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications
        }

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}
```

I'm trying to redirect all www to non www traffic but not 100% sure on how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello
in your server_name directive you have to let only the non-www and add a new derictive to your config file as bellow

server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

Let me know if it's work for you.

Comment: Can you be little more specific? :) Maybe answer the question? Unclear where to write what :)

Comment: this question is closed, I could not write a proper comment